# Does Visual Studio 2017 Community (.NET Framework 4.6.2) support Oracle 8i

Tags: oracle, oracle-8i, odp.net

Does Visual Studio 2017 Community (.NET Framework 4.6.2) support Oracle 8i?

I am trying to connect with .NET Framework 4.6.2 to a production Oracle 8i database.

I googled it, but I can not find anything which is related to this topic. 
I checked also [this site](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cb92fb/connecting-to-oracle-database-through-C-Sharp/) but that is for Windows 2008 R2.

I tried Oracle 19 and Oracle 18 and it works. But I can't find what the oldest version is that is still compatible with .NET Framework (like Oracle 8 or Oracle 9) .

I tried to connect using ODP.NET Managed Driver but it was unsuccessful.

I am an Oracle Developer and Web Developer for the organisation. I have been given the task to test it if it's possible to connect on our  (TEST) database which is Oracle 8i (I believe). Our main database is Oracle 10, but this data is restricted and I cannot manipulate it. This part is for our DBA.

Comment: I know there is a interop matrix for JDBC/Instantclient/OCI in article 207303.1 on MOS. It basically describes the latest drivers have limited support for 11.1 (and newer). But it does not specifically mention ODAC or the managed drivers. They don’t mention server version 8 anymore but the newest driver with most old versions supported is 11.2. anything newer does not work even with 9.

Comment: @eckes, scroll further down in article 207303.1, there you see the Full Interoperability Support Matrix even up to 7.3.4

Comment: Ah thanks missed that, so 10.2 Covers 8.1.7, i guess there was no .net drivers back then.

Comment: BTW one orders what kind of test that is if the database is two major releases older and not useable with anything modern. Maybe an exercise in self Flaggelation? :)

Comment: @eckes, there was a .NET driver in 10.2, however only for .NET framework version 1.x and 2.x - which does not match the requirements of the TO. Driver for .NET framework version 4 has been introduced in Oracle 11.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an 8i database handy to test. If you care about your data it'd be wise to upgrade to a supported version of Oracle ASAP. The last version of Oracle client that can connect to Oracle 8i is an Oracle 10 client (and you need to be on Oracle 8.1.7 server-side).

If you can find an Oracle 10 client install (either full-fat or the instant client), then you might be able to get it to work. - [Phil](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/5555/phil%E1%B5%80%E1%B4%B9)

The article referenced in the question is rather bad. Listed prerequisites are wrong/outdated (was even in 2015), it does not properly use the `tnsnames.ora` file, and does not consider 32/64-Bit topic.

See my answer to [Does ASP.NET MVC5 support Oracle 8i](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57574872) on Stack Overflow. - [wernfried-domscheit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/32815/wernfried-domscheit)